# getting npm error while installing npm in windows

Tags: npm

```
$ npm install -g
addLocal Could not install c:\learn
Windows_NT 6.1.7601
argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g"
node v0.12.0
npm  v2.5.1
code EISDIR
errno -4068
```

EISDIR, read

If you need help, you may report this error at:
   http://github.com/npm/npm/issues

Please include the following file with any support request:

```
   c:\learn\npm-debug.log
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 14:  1568 Signal 112              (core dumped) "$basedir/node.exe" "$basedir/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

which package you want to install??

the command you are trying is not valid.

`npm install -g express`

`npm install express -g`

`express` is package which is install after this command.

`-g` means package is install globally in your system.

Comment: i am facing the same error after using the above code the following command. npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (https://github.com/themacclesoft/hljs-cdn-release.git) fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/themacclesoft/hljs-cdn-release.git/'